# sum of datatable column containing forward slash

Tags: c#, datatable

I have a datatable column  which contains a pair of two values (resolved/pending) seperated by forward slash '/' for eg : (10/22)

```
ColumnABC
---------
1/2
5/8
1/3
```

Now I want to calculate sum of this column 'ColumnABC' as (7/13)

I tried something like

```
 string expression = "SUM(" + dt.Columns[i].ColumnName + ")";
 int sum = Convert.ToInt32(dt.Compute(expression, ""));
```

This works fine for all other columns containing int values but throws exception for this 'ColumnABC' : `Syntax error in aggregate argument: Expecting a single column argument with possible 'Child' qualifier.`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you have access to LINQ (i.e. .NET 3.5+):

```
var tuple = dt.Rows.Cast<DataRow>()
                   .Select(row => row["ColumnABC"].ToString().Split('/'))
                   .Select(strs => new Tuple<int, int>(
                         Int32.Parse(strs[0]),
                         Int32.Parse(strs[1])))
                   .Aggregate((curr, next) => new Tuple<int, int>(
                        curr.Item1 + next.Item1,
                        curr.Item2 + next.Item2));

var result = String.Format("{0}/{1}", tuple.Item1, tuple.Item2);
```

Comment: Thanks @decPL !! As column names are dynamic and are unknown I had to make a slight change in your code :

.Select(row => row[dt.Columns[i].ColumnName].ToString().Split('/'))

Answer (score 3):

First, acknowledge that there is clearly a problem with your data source.

Your best bet is to create a function in the DB that will split these out into two fields to be returned to your repository.

If you can't change the DB schema, then just loop over each record, applying a function to split the items in your code, or something like this:

```
var resolved = dt.Rows.ToList<DataRow>.Sum(r => r[i].Split("/")[0])
var pending = dt.Rows.ToList<DataRow>.Sum(r => r[i].Split("/")[1])
```

Anyway, that's off the top of my head...

Comment: @decPL's answer is similar, but far more elegant, and got in before mine. Whiskey and coding advice !FTW.

Comment: I like both answers.  Yours doubles up the string splitting but is way easier to read.

Answer (score 1):

"int sum" makes no sense.  You have a fraction (integers are whole numbers).  I think you are going to have to iterate through the values or write something very crazy.

```
     DataTable table = new DataTable();
     table.Columns.Add( "fraction", typeof( string ) );
     table.Rows.Add( "1/2" );
     table.Rows.Add( "5/8" );
     table.Rows.Add( "1/3" );

     int numerator = 0;
     int denominator = 0;
     foreach ( DataRow row in table.Rows )
     {
        string[] split = row[ 0 ].ToString().Split( '/' );
        numerator += int.Parse( split[ 0 ] );
        denominator += int.Parse( split[ 1 ] );
     }
     MessageBox.Show( numerator + "/" + denominator );
```

It also probably makes more sense to store these values in two separate columns, then you could just get the sum of each column easily using standard sql.

Comment: He wants to sum all the items before the slash, and then sum all the items after the slash. The slash is used as a separator, not a divide operator.

Comment: Ok.   Well, once he has the two numbers separately he can do whatever he wants :)  But you make a good point, so I'll remove my line about how to divide the two numbers.